# Why am I getting form is invalid error in django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

During development of website in Django web framework I am getting form is invalid error when validating form.

I have searched online for solution but not able to solve my problem.

My files are as below.

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null= True)
    cont_no = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null= True)
    pincode = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.f_name

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null= True)
    uniq_price = models.IntegerField(default=0) 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    cust_name = models.ForeignKey(Customer,related_name='first_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prod_name = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='uniqe_price', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unit_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:  
        model = Order  
        fields = "__all__"
```

**views.py**

```
def add_order(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST) 

        form.save() 
        return redirect("place_ord")                        

    else:
        form = CustomerForm()
```

**home.html**

```
 <form id="myForm" action="{% url 'add_order' %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <h1>add order</h1>

      <label>Customer</label>
      <select id="custs" name="customer">
        <option value="">Select Customer</option>                    
        {% for cust in customers %}
          <option id="{{ cust.id }}" value="{{ cust.f_name }}">
                {{ cust.f_name }}
          </option>
        {% endfor %}
       </select><br><br>
       <label>Product</label>
        <select id="singleSelectTextDDJS" name="prods" onchange="singleSelectChangeText()">
        <option>Select Product</option>                    
        {% for prod in products %}
          <option value="{{ prod.uniq_price }}">
              {{ prod.name }}
          </option>
        {% endfor %}
       </select><br><br>
       <label>Price:</label>
      <input type="text" name="price" class="Pric" id="textFieldTextJS" readonly=""><br><br>

      Qualitys:<input type="number" id="qty" class="qtys" name="quality"><br><br>

      Total price:<input type="text" name="totals" class="totals" id="total" readonly="">
      <br><br>
      <button type="submit" name="submit">place order</button>       
    </form>
```

Error

```
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 453, in save
    'created' if self.instance._state.adding else 'changed',
ValueError: The Order could not be created because the data didn't validate.
```

I am not able to validating my form & could anyone guide me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: what are the form errors?

Comment: just display 'form is invalid'.

Comment: you need to print `form.errors` somewhere, e.g. `{{ form.errors }}` in your template. "form is invalid" isn't `form.errors`.

Comment: why you are not rendering the form `{{ form }}` like this in template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with your options that you have given in your form.

`value` should be the `pk` of that object.
ex -

```
 <select id="custs" name="customer">
        <option value="">Select Customer</option>                    
        {% for cust in customers %}
          <option id="cust_{{ cust.id }}" value="{{cust.pk}}">
                {{ cust.f_name }}
          </option>
        {% endfor %}
       </select>
```

The value is not validating with select fields. Try to put only valid values in all options.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check whether your form is valid before saving it:

```
def add_order(request):
  if request.method == "POST":

    form = CustomerForm(request.POST) 
    if form.is_valid():
       form.save() 
       return redirect("place_ord")                        
    else:
       print(form.errors)
  else:
    form = CustomerForm()
  return render(request, template, {'form':form')
```

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#the-view)

Comment: I have tried it also but it goes to else block everytime so my question is my form becoming invalid everytime.

Comment: Dont forget to render form in template `{{ form }}` @Moon

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant form handler:

```
def add_order(request):
    form = CustomerForm(request.POST or None) 
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save() 
        return redirect("place_ord")                        
    return render(request, 'myapp/form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari It works perfectly well. If method is 'GET', it render as normal; if method is 'POST' and error occurred, the form error message will display in the frontend.

Comment: did ypu try? if it is `get` request   you will pass like this  `form = CustomerForm(None)` and `is_valid()` is called with form data

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari I learn this pattern from  [Daniel Greenfeld's keynote](https://www.slideshare.net/pydanny/advanced-django-forms-usage/33) 7 years ago and use it in all of our codebase.